ELY23005: Unable to load OpenID provider metadata from http://localhost:8080/realms/My_Realm/.well-known/openid-configuration
I'm trying to integrate Keycloak 25 with WildFly 26, but I'm facing an issue where my application is supposed to redirect to the Keycloak login page for authentication. Instead, I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error.
In the logs, I see the following warning:
**WARN [org.wildfly.security.http.oidc] (default task-1) ELY23005: Unable to load OpenID provider metadata from http://localhost:8080/realms/My_Realm/.well-known/openid-configuration
**
However, when I manually access this URL in the browser, I get a valid JSON response.
Here are the relevant configuration details:
Standalone.xml:
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron-oidc-client:1.0">
    <secure-deployment name="gui_QA.war">
        <client-id>My_Realm</client-id>
        <provider-url>http://localhost:8080/realms/My_Realm</provider-url>
        <ssl-required>NONE</ssl-required>
        <credential name="secret" secret="..." />
    </secure-deployment>
</subsystem>


web.xml:
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>app</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/index1.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>MY_ROLE</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>OIDC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>My_Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>MY_ROLE</role-name>
</security-role>


oidc.json:
{
  "realm": "My_Realm",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/realms/My_Realm",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "gui_QA",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "..."
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "principal-attribute": "preferred_username",
  "public-client": false,
  "bearer-only": false
}


I've been stuck on this for two days and can't figure out why it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
